# Long click for right click emulation? (XFCE)

Tags: xorg, xfce, manjaro, touch-screen

I'm looking for a way to emulate a right click press when I hold down my left mouse click. I've seen some questions like this on askubuntu, and a raspberry pi forum, but I can't adapt them to work in XFCE. I'm using an X230t, so preferably it would be better to have this only apply to the touchscreen, but it's also fine if this is a global setting.

Raspbery pi forum: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=121602

I tried to adapt the xorg config file from the link above, but I couldn't figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a brilliant program for this: https://github.com/PeterCxy/evdev-right-click-emulation

Not sure how I missed it, but it works great and on other DEs as well.